# Finding the appropriate fitting function for a coherence length measurement

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser, coherence

I'm studying Coherent Optics in Experimental Physics, and I intend to determine the coherence length of a two beam interference. To do that, I used an He-Ne laser, a Michelson interferometer and a CCD. The scheme of the setting is the following:

[image]

The coherence length, $l_c$, is defined as the distance $2d$ needed to the decay of the contrast fuction, $K$, to $1/e$.
I positionated the adjustable mirror on different positions and captured photos on the CCD. From those photos I determined the contrast using ImageJ. Then I did a fit on ROOT using, by guess, a cosine function for the base, $y(x)=a\cos(x\times b + c)+d$. I got the following picture:

[image]

With the resultant fitting function, I could compute $l_c$, and I got $l_c=19.68cm$. I was searching on the web (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_length) and I found that this coherence length is typical of a multimode helium–neon laser. I did not know that my laser was a multimode one (I'm new at Optics), and so, I tried to know more about it. I found on this MIT video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LixwAXsN8vg, that this multimode laser can produce a beam with multiple frequencies.

My main objective now is to choose a theoretical fitting function instead of a guessed one and use it to compute the coherence length. To determine my contrast function $K$ for fitting, I need to compute $K=\frac{|\Gamma{(\tau)}|}{\Gamma{(0)}}$ where:

$$\Gamma{(\tau)}=\int_0^\infty |E(\nu)|^2 e^{-i 2\pi\nu\tau} d\nu$$

I just need to find $E(\nu)$. My problem here is how should I do it? Should I assume something like $E(\nu)=E_0\delta(\nu-\nu_1)+E_0\delta(\nu-\nu_2)$. Should I use gaussian functions instead of dirac delta functions?

Comment: Your interferometer is a Fourier spectrometer, isn't it? It should give you a high resolution spectrum of your laser.

Comment: I didn't have time to study the laser in laboratory... My teacher didn't even tell me that the laser was a multimode one. That's why I'm requesting some advice of physicists that already have done this experimentation.

Comment: If you don't have access to the experiment any longer, then it's pretty much a done deal and you have to use the data you have. That the laser is multimode should have been obvious from the description and the resolution of the interferometer is something you have to work out from the geometry. If it can resolve the laser lines, then you have your model. IMHO the contrast is a very poor use of what you have here, you should have done a complete Fourier sweep using the interference pattern, instead. Water under the bridge, I guess.

Comment: I think you're right, but I  already  got in trouble on first place. As I said before I'm new at Optics. I'm doing a course of experimental physics, where this is only one of the many experimentations that I need to do. I didn't had in the past any theoretical support about lasers, optic Fourier transforms, coherent optics, Michelson interferometer etc. I followed a record, that said I would only need 4 points distance-contrast to determine the coherence length. I thought it wasn't enough, and so I managed to get 10 points. I think all this course is badly structured...